# Ubuntu crashes on windows: 0x80040326 Wsl error

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu 22.04 app installed on top of Windows.  It worked fine until one day it crashed and now all I get is this error code when I try to start Ubuntu on windows.

```
Error: 0x80040326
Error code: Wsl/Service/0x80040326
Press any key to continue...
```

I'm running windows powershell version 2

```
 wsl --list --verbose
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04    Running         2
```

I'm using Microsoft Office Home 10.0.22621 Build 22621

Any thoughts on what I can do?  Google doesn't have many hits for "0x80040326"

Installing a fresh copy doesn't work:

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username: xxxxx
New password:
Retype new password:
Sorry, passwords do not match.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
Try again? [y/N] y
New password:
Retype new password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Installation successful!
Error: 0x80040326
Error code: Wsl/Service/0x80040326
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: *"I'm running windows powershell version 2"*. No, you're running WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) version 2. *"I'm using Microsoft Office Home 10.0.22621 Build 22621"*. No, you're using Windows 11 Version 10.0.22621 (Build 22621). I know this sounds pedantic, but my intentions are good: Getting these things right will help you **a lot** when googling  for solutions to your problems.

Answer (score 226):

I had a same problem, but just solved it.

Update your wsl system.

```
wsl --update
```

Comment: I had to do it multiple times

Comment: Following up to @user541686. Plus the MS Store version has lots of annoying unsolved issues: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9231

Comment: Also worked for me and, although the update was quick, I still had to wait a few minutes for Windows pop up a notification stating the Update was completed until it started working again.

Comment: solved by pressing 'repair' in the wsl settings menu

Comment: Also: don't use again 'wsl.memory', 'wsl.processors' or 'wsl.localhostForwarding' in your .wslconfig (they don't work anymore for some reason)

Comment: I had to do a `wsl --shutdown` to make sure it is stopped before retrying, and it finally worked.

Answer (score 16):

Windows updates are notorious for breaking things in the background.

The best way to fix this issue will be:

1. Open a PowerShell or Command Prompt window in Administrator mode
2. Run the command `wsl.exe --update`
3. Run `wsl.exe` again to see if you can access your default WSL distro otherwise reboot your laptop or desktop and that will fix the issue

Alternatively, you can also rollback the kernel version to establish a working subsystem with the command `wsl.exe --update --rollback`

Comment: This didn't immediately work for me, I had to restart WSL. `wsl --shutdown` and then launching another terminal. Note that this will likely kill any processes that were previously running in WSL, but at this point you probably can't touch/save them anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Got the same issue after updating windows yesterday.

```
wsl --update
```

This worked as others have said, however it still crashed when trying to start wsl right after running the command. Started working in like a minute or so after running the wsl update, not sure if there was some background process running or something...

Answer (score 3):

I started having this issue today, this worked for me.

```
netsh winsock reset
```

then restart computer

from this issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9331#issuecomment-1356896162

Answer (score 2):

For people facing issues downloading from the Microsoft Store:

```
wsl --update --web-download
```

Will download from GitHub instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to restart the following service to make it work:

1. LxsxManager
2. HV Host Service

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**:
I was getting following error while launching ubuntu-22.04

```
Error: 0x80040326
Error code: Wsl/Service/0x80040326
```

**Reason**:
Ubuntu needed update

**Solution**:
open command prompt in normal or admin mode

run command in command prompt to check ubuntu installed version(optional)

```
 wsl -l -v
```

Now, run below command to update ubuntu to latest

```
 wsl --update
```

Its Done.
Below is my command prompt output in non-admin mode, for reference.

Command prompt output:

```
C:\Users\Brij>wsl -l -v
  NAME                         STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04                 Running         2
  docker-desktop-data          Running         2
  docker-desktop               Running         2

C:\Users\Brij>wsl --update
Checking for updates.
Updating Windows Subsystem for Linux...^C
C:\Users\Brij>
```

Comment: `wsl --update` updates WSL, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

For me, just `WSL --update` did not work, but going into Apps and doing repair worked:

- Apps > Installed Apps > Windows Sybsystem for Linux... > Modify > Repair

Answer (score 0):

- `wsl --update`
- `wsl --shutdown`
- waiting one Minute
- start your WSL (e.g. Ubuntu)

this answer is based on https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9867#issuecomment-1489633480

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve this by uninstalling the WSL app and just using the built-in OS version.

To do this, you can right-click it in the Start Menu and click Uninstall.

Alternatively, you can remove it in Apps & Features.